# Mat dialog inside a mat table get a same value when hitting addrow

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, rxjs

here's my table when i tried to open the table

[image]

once i open the dialog it will pop up my table with list

[image]

but once i tried to click the add for row it will gave me the same value

[image]

here's what i did
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-zhfnzy

The problem is how to stay the value in my first index?
and i can choose the second index without moving the first value?

Comment: Question is not clear, can you please explain more about the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you has wrote

```
<!--REMOVE [(ngModel)]-->
<input type="text" formControlName="address" [(ngModel)]="value" />
```

You need remove the [(ngModel)], futhermore **not** use in the same tag [(ngModel)] and formControlName. You're saying Angular that the value is the value of the formControlName and also the value is the variable "value" (has no sense)

BTW, use formControlName in your first two inputs (not formControl)

```
  <input type="" formControl="name" />
  <input type="" formControl="lastname" />
```

Another thing: your question title is about Mat-dialog, I can not see any mat-dialog in your stackblitz :(. give more data or change the title of your question)

**Update** Your openAlertDialog function like

```
  openAlertDialog(index:number) {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AlertDialogComponent, {});

    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
      this.fg.get('Info.'+index+'.address').setValue(result)
    });
  }
```

See how you use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#setValue) to give value to a FormControl. See how you use [get](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#get) to "reach" the formControl

You can use also get in the way

```
((this.fg.get('Info') as FormArray)
              .at(index) as FormGroup)
              .get('address')
```

But to avoid the "cast" I simply use the "dot" notation in a get

**Update 2** The "result" can be also an object if we use some like,e.g.

```
this.dialogRef.close({address:row.symbol,phone:row.name});
```

See that in this case we can pass an object in the "same way" that the FormArray. In this case we can use setValue or [patchValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) to the element of the formArray, some like

```
 this.fg.get('Info.'+index).setValue(result)
 //or
 (this.fg.get('Info') as FormArray).at(index).setValue(result)
```

Comment: try to look again, try to expand the UI screen there's OPEN TABLE

Comment: @AceJi, sorry, I didn't see the button openTable :(. I update the answer: see that you use setValue to give value to a FormControl

Comment: but what if i want to populate address and phone?

Comment: It's the same, first you return not only a "string" else an object, the you can use setValue two times or, if the object you return is in the "same way" of the formArray you can use setValue over the element of the FormArray (I update the answer). The only you need remember is use "setValue" (or pathValue) to give value to an "AbstractControl". An AbstractControl can be a FormControl, or a FormGroup or a FormArray, you first "reach" the AbstractControl and use one of the methods

Comment: this.dialogRef.close({address:row.symbol,phone:row.name});

i try this one but the display is [Object] [Object]

Comment: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-dialog-example-px5fav?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts) see that in this case use setValue to give value to the element of the FormArray, not to a FormControl in the FormArray

Comment: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'id'. this is the error

Comment: Then use patchValue. when you use setValue you need use an object with all the properties, patchValue is not neccesary